# unboxing or toString() is used in sysout in java

Tags: java

We know that when we use objects in sysout(System.out.Println) statement internally it's toString method is called. and with primitive it directly prints. but when we use any Wrapper class type of objects is used say suppose Integer  like following

```
      Integer i = new Integer(10)
      System.out.Println(i);
```

is it toString() is responsible for printing it or Unboxing?

Comment: I think it would only unbox in cases where int was the only option.  Since there is a println(Object), that would probably get called.

Comment: @gurukulki, updated by answer hope it helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick test and debug run shows that `print(Object)` is invoked, not `print(int)`.

A good way to check this is :

```
Integer val = null;
System.out.print(val);
```

If un-boxing were used, this would throw a NullPointerException. This doesn't happen, though, it prints the string `null`, which is the output of `String.valueOf(Object)` when a null is passed in.

Another aspect to bear in mind is that `PrintStream` existed before Java 5. When autoboxing was introduced in Java 5, it had to be ensured that any existing code using `PrintStream` would not suddenly have its behaviour changed. So any existing code calling `print(Object)` must not suddenly have its behaviour changed to call `print(int)` instead, simply because of a new language feature. Backwards compatibility must always be maintained.

Comment: This is interesting, but is it conclusive? There could be an `if` handling nulls.

Comment: An `if` where? There's no magic happening here, and un-boxing a null will *always* throw a NPE.

Comment: @skaffman, you are right, there's no magic happening here, and unboxing a null will always throw a NPE. However, your two lines of code to not demonstrate that this is what is happening. There could be an `if` anywhere along the way checking for nulls. The fact that there isn't one is something we know either by inspecting the source code or checking the docs.

Comment: yar, if unboxing would happen, then NPE would be thrown. This "if" just has nowhere to be placed

Comment: @Bozho, this is all hypothetical. There is no `if` but since the `valueOf` method of String is pure Java, it could contain an `if` (it doesn't), it could use autoboxing (it doesn't). But how do we know? Skaffman's test does not tell us HOW it does its work.

Comment: @yar: It uses the ternary operator.

Answer (score 5):

> (...) but when we use any Wrapper class type
>   of objects is used say suppose Integer
>   like following
>
> ```
>   Integer i = new Integer(10)
>   System.out.println(i);
> ```
>
> is it toString() is responsible for
>   printing it or Unboxing?

You're passing an `Object` to `println` so it's obviously [`println(Object obj)`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/PrintStream.java.html#641) that is called which writes the output of [`String.valueOf(obj)`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html#2831) which calls `obj.toString()` if `obj` is not `null`.

PS: No offense but, why don't you just look at the sources?

**Update:** I've maybe missed the point of the question (which is misleading in its current form if I may). Actually, the question might be:

> (...) but when we use any Wrapper class type
>   of objects is used say suppose Integer
>   like following
>
> ```
>   Integer i = new Integer(10)
>   System.out.println(i);
> ```
>
> What method will be called:
>   `println(Object)` or `println(int)`?

If this is what the question is about, then the answer lies of course in [The Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/). To simplify, the method invoked at run time will be the method that is determined at compile-time. Now, how does the compiler determine the method that will be invoked? Well, this is explained in the section [15.12 Method Invocation Expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#20448). I won't cover all the details, the spec does it better than me but, basically, the first step is to find the class or interface to search, the second step is to find all applicable methods and then to pick up the most specific method, the third step is to verify if the chosen method is appropriate. I'll focus on the 2nd step (which is the interesting one here). As detailed in section [15.12.2 Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2):

> A method is applicable if it is either
>   applicable by subtyping [(§15.12.2.2)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#301185),
>   applicable by method invocation
>   conversion [(§15.12.2.3)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#352591), or it is an
>   applicable variable arity method
>   [(§15.12.2.4)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#301239).
>
> The process of determining
>   applicability begins by determining
>   the potentially applicable methods
>   [(§15.12.2.1)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#316811). The remainder of the
>   process is split into three phases.
>
> ---
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The purpose of the division into
>   phases is to ensure compatibility with
>   older versions of the Java programming
>   language.
>
> ---
>
> The first phase [(§15.12.2.2)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#301185)
>   performs overload resolution without
>   permitting boxing or unboxing
>   conversion, or the use of variable
>   arity method invocation. If no
>   applicable method is found during this
>   phase then processing continues to the
>   second phase.
>
> ---
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This guarantees that any calls that
>   were valid in older versions of the
>   language are not considered ambiguous
>   as a result of the introduction of
>   variable arity methods, implicit
>   boxing and/or unboxing.
>
> ---
>
> The second phase [(§15.12.2.3)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#352591)
>   performs overload resolution while
>   allowing boxing and unboxing, but
>   still precludes the use of variable
>   arity method invocation. If no
>   applicable method is found during this
>   phase then processing continues to the
>   third phase.
>
> ---
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This ensures that a variable arity
>   method is never invoked if an
>   applicable fixed arity method exists.
>
> ---
>
> The third phase [(§15.12.2.4)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#301239)
>   allows overloading to be combined with
>   variable arity methods, boxing and
>   unboxing.
>
> Deciding whether a method is
>   applicable will, in the case of
>   generic methods [(§8.4.4)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#323928),
>   require that actual type arguments be
>   determined. Actual type arguments may
>   be passed explicitly or implicitly. If
>   they are passed implicitly, they must
>   be inferred [(§15.12.2.7)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#341287) from the
>   types of the argument expressions.
>
> If several applicable methods have
>   been identified during one of the
>   three phases of applicability testing,
>   then the most specific one is chosen,
>   as specified in section [§15.12.2.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#301183).
>   See the following subsections for
>   details.

In this particular case, `println(Obj)` is applicable by subtyping (and `println(int)` would be applicable by invocation conversion as boxing/unboxing is a conversion [(§5.3)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#12687)). So the compiler will enter the [phase 1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#301185). And if we look at the last sentence:

> If no method applicable by subtyping is found, the search for applicable methods continues with phase 2 [(§15.12.2.3)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#352591). Otherwise, **the most specific method [(§15.12.2.5)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#301183) is chosen among the methods that are applicable by subtyping**.

Here, there aren't any other methods applicable by subtyping so this is the end, `println(Object)` will be invoked (and thus `toString()` will be called, to answer the initial question).

Comment: i had a doubt that it may unbox and print the primitive int

Comment: @Pascal: This isn't really an API issue, though, it's a question of whether the language itself prefers unboxing to passing the object.

Comment: @skaffman, it's an API issue and has to do with how the String API is specified. String's behavior, being an object and not a primitive, is determined by the API.

Comment: +1 Pascal, please put in the links to the relevant sources... what should he look at and where would he find that?

Comment: @BalusC, yes thanks aren't those hanging out somewhere on the Net?

Comment: @skaffman You might be right and I've updated my answer to cover the language behavior. But at the end, it's an API issue :)

Answer (score 4):

**All of this predates [autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html), which was introduced in 1.5.** The code that answers these questions -- or the API docs -- hasn't changed at all for 1.5+.

Basically, at the end of the line is the `toString` method for non-primitives like instances of `Integer`.

So first, with primitives, there's a different treatment for each one. For `int`, for instance

> Prints an integer. The string produced
>   by String.valueOf(int) is translated
>   into bytes according to the platform's
>   default character encoding, and these
>   bytes are written in exactly the
>   manner of the write(int) method.

But for objects like `Integer`, println calls [print](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(int)) which:

> Print an object. The string produced
>   by the String.valueOf(Object) method
>   is translated into bytes according to
>   the platform's default character
>   encoding, and these bytes are written
>   in exactly the manner of the
>   write(int) method.

So what does `valueOf` use? This is the answer to your question: for `Integer` its `toString`  method is called. This is from the docs on [`String.valueOf`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object))

> if the argument is null, then a string
>   equal to "null"; otherwise, the value
>   of obj.toString() is returned.

Comment: What do you want to explain here. my question is simple toString() or Unboxing? which one is responsible?